# Ion ripple effect not working inside a plain html button

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

In an Ionic v4 app, the ion ripple effect isn't showing while clicking on a plain html button:

```
<button type="submit" form="myForm">
  <ion-ripple-effect></ion-ripple-effect>
  <ion-icon src="pathToButtonIcon\button-icon.svg"></ion-icon>
  <ion-text text-capitalize>buttonText</ion-text>
</button>
```

A similar example is given in [The Ionic Docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/ripple-effect#usage), but it's not working for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had to add the `ion-activatable` class to the button to make it work:

```
<button class="ion-activatable" type="submit" form="myForm">
  <ion-ripple-effect></ion-ripple-effect>
  <ion-icon src="pathToButtonIcon\button-icon.svg"></ion-icon>
  <ion-text text-capitalize>buttonText</ion-text>
</button>
```